# Anyone can suggest some Game Frameworks for GNU/Linux?

Tags: xna, linux

So I've been developing a little bit with XNA + C# in Windows, not really much: just some 2D stuff, but I've found that XNA is a really good framework.

I'm a GNU/Linux user, and I'm definitely migrating my desktop to Gentoo Linux (I've been using Arch in my laptop for a while now).

But, of course, I need a C# + XNA alternative... I'm not really an expert in any language, so I can really pick up anything (except, maybe, Functional ones), I prefer C-Like languages like Java or Ruby, I tried Python but found the Whitespace syntax confusing.

I would like to hear some of you'r suggestions, I'm not asking for "the best", but for "some suggestions", so I think this is objective enough.

Probably you're going to suggest C++ + SDL, but I would prefer something more "High Level" like XNA, but I'm open to discuss anything.

So... any ideas ?

**Note:** I think this questions meets the guidelines for this site, if it doesn't: please not only downvote this question, but comment on what can I do to improve it.
Thanks.

**PS: 2D Games, not 3D**

Comment: As the choice of which of framework is somewhat dependent on what specifically you want to make, you may get more useful answers if you refine your question with more details the kinds of games you are interested in building.

Comment: "which tech to use" questions are explicitly off topic as given by the [faq].  http://meta.gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/695/are-what-should-i-use-to-do-x-questions-really-on-topic-and-good

Answer (score 1):

> But, of course, I need a C# + XNA alternative...

Not necessarily try [MonoGame](https://www.monogame.net). Otherwise I hear good things about [Love](https://love2d.org/).

Answer (score 0):

If you like XNA and C#, try [MonoGame](http://monogame.codeplex.com/), and continue working with the tools you already know.

[PyGame](http://www.pygame.org/news.html) is a popular choice for Python programmers, and fairly popular in general I'd say.

You can also go the browser/HTML5 route and use something like [Crafty](http://craftyjs.com/), and hit multiple platforms (including mobile, and of course Linux) very easily.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to code in Ruby, [Gosu](https://github.com/jlnr/gosu) is a lightweight framework that gives you a basic game loop and and 2D drawing support (quads, images and fonts). There is also [Chingu](https://github.com/ippa/chingu) which builds on top of Gosu and adds alot off extra stuff like animations, a basic game object, etc.

For Java, there is [Slick2D](http://slick.cokeandcode.com/) but i haven't used that in ages, so no idea if it is still developed/supported